# ILIKE search in string only works on its first part?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Users` table with a `name` field which contains the users full name.

I wrote a search function that should allow finding users by their first name or their last name, but it only returns results for first names.

For example if I have a user: `user.name = 'John Smith'`, if I enter 'John' I get the record back, but if I enter 'Smith' I get no results. Here's my search code:

```
name_users = User.where('name ILIKE ?', params["search_text"] + '%').all
```

How can I allow searching by last name?

Comment: `name_users = User.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params["search_text"]}%").all`  - try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
name_users = User.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params["search_text"]}%")
```

Comment: @pascalbetz yes, it is not needed

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` and `ILIKE` do pattern matching, and with `%` at the end you're only matching the term at the start of the string, so you're able to match by first name only. Since the last name has characters in front of it in the string, it doesn't get matched. [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/functions-matching.html):

> LIKE pattern matches always cover the entire string. To match a pattern anywhere within a string, the pattern must therefore start and end with a percent sign.

You should match both the beginning and the end by adding `%` in the beginning of your query,:

`name_users = User.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params["search_text"]}%")`

Comment: .all is not needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the full power of SQL. So you can add another `%` before the text you search to indicate that you want to search for a string match at any position in the column.

```
query = "%#{params['name']}%"
User.where('name ILIKE ?', query)
```

You do not need the `all`

Comment: This implies there are columns names `last_name` and `nick_name`, but the question only has one `name` column.

Comment: @p4sh4 you are right. I misread the question. Updated my answer.